# KendoUI - How to create controls at runtime based on user input?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to create different type of controls in a KendoUI grid column at runtime?  The scenario is, I have 2 columns in my grid.  The first column displays a dropdown list which has the some strings like, 'Name', 'StartDate', etc.  When user selects a value from it, I want to show an appropriate control in the 2nd column.  If the user picks 'StartDate', I want to show the 'DateTime' control.  Can you please let me know how to do this thru ASP.Net MVC 5 wrapper?

Sample Code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ArulUI.Models.UserFilter>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.ForeignKey(f => f.FilterName, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Filters"], "Name", "Name");
        columns.Bound(f => f.FilterValue).ClientTemplate("#= gridValueColumnFormatter(data) #");

        columns.Template(t => { }).HeaderTemplate("").ClientTemplate(@"
            <a href='javascript: void(0)' class='abutton delete' onclick='deleteRow(this)' title='remove'>remove</a>")
             .Width(100).Title("");
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
    {
        toolbar.Create();
        toolbar.Save();
    })

    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .Editable(e => e.DisplayDeleteConfirmation(false))
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Events(e => e.Edit("onEdit"))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(f => f.Id);
            model.Field(f => f.Id).Editable(false);
        })
        .Create(create => create.Action("Filter_Create", "Home"))
        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Filter_Delete", "Home"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("Filter_Read", "Home"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("Filter_Update", "Home"))
    )
)

<script>

    function gridValueColumnFormatter(dataRow) {
        var returnValue = "";
        if (dataRow.FilterName == "DateTimeRange") {
            returnValue = kendo.format('{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm}', new Date(dataRow.FilterValue));
        }
        else {
            returnValue = dataRow.FilterValue;
        }

        return returnValue;
    }


    function onEdit(e) {
        var actElement = document.activeElement;
        //alert(txt.id);
        if (actElement.id == "FilterValue") {
            var selectedValue = e.model.FilterValue;
            var selectedDate = Date.parse(selectedValue);
            console.log(selectedValue);
            console.log(selectedDate);

            if (e.model.FilterName == "DateTimeRange") {
                if (isNaN(selectedDate)) {
                    initDatePicker(new Date());
                } else {
                    //initDatePicker(selectedValue);
                    $("#FilterValue").kendoDateTimePicker({
                        value: new Date(selectedValue)
                    });
                }
            } else {
                if (!isNaN(selectedDate)) {
                    $("#FilterValue").val("");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function initDatePicker(dateValue) {
        $("#FilterValue").empty();

        $("#FilterValue").kendoDateTimePicker({
            value: new Date(dateValue),
            format: "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm",
            parseFormats: "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm"
        });
        var dateTimePicker = $("#FilterValue").data("kendoDateTimePicker");
        dateTimePicker.value(dateValue);

    }

    function disposeDatePicker() {
        var datepicker = $("#FilterValue").data("kendoDateTimePicker");
        if (datepicker) {
            popup = datepicker.dateView.popup;
            element = popup.wrapper[0] ? popup.wrapper : popup.element;

            //Move the shared calendar to the body
            kendo.ui.DatePicker.sharedCalendar.element.hide().appendTo(document.body);

            //remove popup element;
            element.remove();
            //unwrap element
            var input = datepicker.element.show();

            input.removeClass("k-input"); //.css("width", "auto");
            input.insertBefore(datepicker.wrapper);

            datepicker.wrapper.remove();

            //remove DatePicker object
            input.removeData("kendoDateTimePicker");
        }
    }

    function deleteRow(element) {
        grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.removeRow($(element).closest("tr"));
    }

    function createRow() {
        grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.addRow();
    }
</script>

Controller:

public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public static List<ArulUI.Models.Filter> ListFilter = new List<ArulUI.Models.Filter>();
        public static List<UserFilter> ListUserFilters = new List<UserFilter>();
        public void Seed()
        {
            ListFilter = new List<Models.Filter>{
                new ArulUI.Models.Filter { Name = "Name", Type="string"},
                new ArulUI.Models.Filter { Name = "Dept", Type="string"},
                new ArulUI.Models.Filter { Name = "Age", Type="string"},
                new ArulUI.Models.Filter { Name = "DateTimeRange", Type="datetime"}
            };

            ListUserFilters = new List<UserFilter> {
                new UserFilter { Id = 1, FilterName="Name", FilterValue = "Empty"},
                new UserFilter { Id = 2, FilterName="Dept", FilterValue = "Empty2"},
                //new UserFilter { Id = 2, FilterName="DateTimeRange", FilterValue = "12/20/2013 10:00"}
            };
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            this.Seed();
            ViewData["Filters"] = ListFilter.Select(f => new
            {
                Name = f.Name,
                Type = f.Type
            });

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Filter_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            return Json(ListUserFilters.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }

        public ActionResult Filter_Delete([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, UserFilter userFilter)
        {
            if (userFilter != null && ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var target = ListUserFilters.Where(f => f.Id == userFilter.Id).FirstOrDefault();

                if (target != null)
                {
                    ListUserFilters.Remove(target);
                }
            }

            return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Filter_Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, UserFilter userFilter)
        {
            if (userFilter != null && ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var target = ListUserFilters.Where(f => f.Id == userFilter.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                if (target != null)
                {
                    int targetIndex = ListUserFilters.IndexOf(target);
                    ListUserFilters[targetIndex].FilterName = target.FilterName;
                    ListUserFilters[targetIndex].FilterValue = target.FilterValue;
                }
            }

            return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
        }

        public ActionResult Filter_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, UserFilter userFilter)
        {
            userFilter.Id = ListUserFilters[ListUserFilters.Count - 1].Id + 1;
            userFilter.Id = 10;
            ListUserFilters.Add(userFilter);

            return Json(new[] { userFilter }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }


        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll likely have to implement that yourself, e.g. by binding the dropdown's [change event](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/dropdownlist#events-change) to store the selected control type (e.g. "kendoDatePicker") in a variable somewhere, then have a data structure that gives you the appropriate options for each control type. Then you can make your editor template for the second column dynamic based on that control type variable.

If you use inline editing and you want to replace the editor directly, your dropdown change handler might look something like this (note that in order to display the various value types nicely, you'll probably need a complex display template as well):

```
change: function (e) {
    // select other column by index, for example
    var secondColumn = $(e.sender.element).closest("td").siblings().eq(0);
    var name = $(secondColumn).find("input").attr("name");
    secondColumn.empty(); // remove existing editor (you should also call .destroy() for existing widgets in there!)
    var model = grid._modelForContainer(secondColumn); // get associated data model from kendoGrid instance

    $("<input data-bind='value: " + name + "'/>").appendTo(secondColumn).kendoDatePicker();
    kendo.bind(secondColumn, model); // bind the model again manually
}
```

See [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/TGgH8/3/)

If you use in-cell editing, then you should use the editor template as I suggested before; the template function for your dynamic column might look something like this:

```
editor: function (container, options) {
    // model.typeTitle is set by the dropdown column
    if (options.model.typeTitle === "DateTime") {
        $("<input data-bind='value:name' />")
            .appendTo(container).kendoDateTimePicker(controlOptions["kendoDateTimePicker"]);
    } else if (options.model.typeTitle === "String") {
        $("<input data-bind='value:name' />")
            .appendTo(container);
    } else if (options.model.typeTitle === "Number") {
        $("<input data-bind='value:name' />")
            .appendTo(container).kendoNumericTextBox();
    }  
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/42BWh/4/)

Comment: I tried something like you noted.  But I don't know how to replace the edit control of the 2nd column.  I added the code in the question.  Can you please help?

Comment: Thank you Lars.  I tried your suggestion and though it creates the control, the selected value is not getting updated to the source.  I managed to do the same in some other way [updated code in the question], but there are 2 issues.  1. The DateTimePicker box is blank and it always shows the Today's date on expanding.  2.  It briefly shows 2 calendars when navigating the months.  I appreciate if you can take a look at my code and let me know what I'm missing.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @sarav updated again (I didn't use your code, but hope you can adapt it from my solution)

Comment: I very much appreciate your help here Lars.  I tried with your code but it is not working when I change the edit mode to 'incell'.  I updated the JSfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/42BWh/1/).  Can you please take a look?  Thank you.

Comment: @sarav you shouldn't use the edit event for that but the editor template of your column; I updated the post

Comment: Thank you Lars :).  I appreciate this.  Question though, do you know how to do this same dynamic editing template in the ASP.Net MVC?  Because the whole model is not available to the editing template, so I can't check 'typeTitle' inside the template.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this and unfortunately I can't look into it right now - I imagine you could try to simply write out the JS code (the "if" block) in your editor template (i.e. not use the fluid syntax at all there); if that doesn't work, I'd suggest asking a separate question on here on how to convert the JS template to an MVC template (or ask Telerik support)

Comment: another option (although not very pretty): use the DataBound event of the grid to replace the editor tempate (i.e.: loop through grid.options.columns and set `column.editor = function (container, options) ...` for the respective column name)

Comment: Thank you Lars.  I wanted to achieve the same inside the ListView.  Asked another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009030/kendoui-listview-how-to-show-dynamic-controls-at-runtime-in-edittemplate).  Can you please let me know if you've any ideas?